# How can I create an image "change" effect in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-effects

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="container">
     <img src="images/1.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/2.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/3.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/4.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/5.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/6.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
</div>
```

What I want to do is use the existing images I am using in the image tags and every 2-5 seconds I want to slowly fade one image and in it's place show another image (one of the existing images in the other image tags) and I want this effect to take place randomly.

I've never done this before so not sure how to go about this? I am thinking fade in and fade out makes sense but not sure how to tackle this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Fade-in and fade-out is right... What exactly is the problem? Random numbers? The actual fade functions? Loops? Doesn't look like you put much research effort into this post...

Comment: I am new to Jquery so it took me a while to find that fade in and fade out was the way to go.  I am still looking at how to do it.

Comment: `$(element).fadeIn()` and `$(element).fadeOut()`. Done... What's next? What was the next thing you're having trouble with?

Comment: how do I randomly select an image to change with another and how to target that fade in and fade out.

Comment: You have 6 image elements. All you need is to randomly select one... Fade it in... then randomly select another one, fade the old one out and the new one in... I'm still not seeing where the problem is here...

Comment: I'd really like to help out @ariel - but I'm not going to do the work for you. You'll have to show that you put some effort into at least *trying* to solve this. Break it up into little parts and deal with each one individually. Then start connecting them.

Comment: @ariel Just whipped up a really simple solution for you that includes some of the logic in how I approached it. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so like any programming task you want to break something like this down into simple steps. In this case, maybe something like this:

1. When the page loads, only show the first image. To do this, you should have a `display:none` CSS rule on all of the images EXCEPT for the first one. This can easily be accomplished by created a class called `hide` and applying it to the HTML. We could also manage this via JS, but that may cause bugs depending on the internet connection that your users have...
2. Every five seconds, fade the current image out, and fade the next one in.
3. If we are on the last image, make sure we go back to the first image in the list.

That's pretty much all we need to do, so let's write some code:

First, let's refactor your markup to use an id for the container and then add the CSS class to all images but the first.

```
<div id="img_container">
     <img src="images/1.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/2.png" class="hide image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/3.png" class="hide image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/4.png" class="hide image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/5.png" class="hide image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/6.png" class="hide image_wall_thumbnail" />
</div>
```

Next, let's write a little CSS:

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Okay now is the "tricky" part where we write some JS:

```
$(function() {
  //cache dom elements and set init vars
  var $img = $('#img_container').find('img'),
      max = $img.length, //how many images you have in the container
      current = 0; //we will start the script at the first item

  //Every five seconds, run the code within the handler
  setInterval(function(){
    $($img[current]).fadeOut('fast', function(){
      determineIndex(); //Update the index of the image in the img array
      $($img[current]).fadeIn();
    });
  }, 5000);

  function determineIndex () {
    current = (current === max - 1) ? 0 : (current + 1);
  }
});
```

Now here's the demo! http://jsfiddle.net/T2nzh/

Comment if you have any questions about how the javascript works. :)

EDIT: Okay, so if you want to just randomly swap out image sources, check this out. The html you want:

```
<div id="img_container">
     <img src="images/1.png" style="background:red" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/2.png" style="background:silver" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/3.png" style="background:purple" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/4.png" style="background:yellow" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/5.png" style="background:green" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/6.png" style="background:blue" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
</div>

<div id="img_spares" style="display:none;">
     <img src="images/7.png" style="background:magenta" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
    <img src="images/8.png" style="background:brown" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
$(function() {
  //cache dom elements and set init vars
  var $img = $('#img_container'),
      $spares = $('#img_spares'),
      max = $img.find('img').length,
      spares_max = $spares.find('img').length;

  //Every five seconds, run the code within the handler
  setInterval(function(){
    $($img.find('img')[randomIndex(0,max)]).fadeOut('fast', function(){
      var $el = $(this),
          el_source = $el.attr('style'),
          $swap = $($spares.find('img')[randomIndex(0,spares_max)]),
          swap_source = $swap.attr('style');

      $el.attr('style', swap_source).fadeIn();
      $swap.attr('style', el_source);
    });
  }, 1000);

  function randomIndex (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
});
```

And the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T2nzh/3/

Comment: Great answer! Pity that the OP didn't put this much effort into the question :-P

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthew! I really appreciate the help.  I have a question about the max variable.  In the comment you ask how many images you have in the container, should I actually replace ".image" with the number or a variable that has the amount? And in the fiddle it seems it only shows the red box and fades out for a long while then shows again rather than all the other colored boxes showing.  Thanks!

Comment: The `max` variable automatically determines the number of images that you put in the container. So I set this up so that it goes one by one through each of the images, as opposed to a random order. All you'd have to do to randomize it would be to edit the `determineIndex()` function. Now, if you want to have all images display at once and then replace one at random, you'll need a slightly different approach.

Comment: @ariel Just updated with the random swapper. It requires a little different markup, and you'll need to change the JS to swap image sources instead of just styles. You can use `attr('src')` instead of `.attr('style')`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow! Thanks Matthew.  I'll be sure to learn as much as possible by breaking this up!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I do have to use document.ready in place of the function(), correct?

Comment: Happy to help! So `$(function(){})` is the same as doing `$(document).ready()`. Use whichever one is easier for you to read. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39659/discussion-between-ariel-and-matthew-blancarte)

Comment: Hey Matthew, thanks for the help. I was able to remove that error but the images don't swap.I am using document.ready and that error resolved but the images don't swap.

Comment: also I am wondering if we could still do this without the spares div where we are using display none? I am stacking all images next to each other rather than on top as you have in the example.

Comment: Now that you have some working code, go ahead and ask another question that has a more specific goal. :) You can do it in many different ways. My example is probably not how I would go about it. I would probably store image paths in an array and then just use the array instead of the DOM... I would probably avoid stacking all images in the same div, though.

Answer (score 1):

take a look:

```
<div class="container">
     <img src="images/1.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/2.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/3.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/4.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/5.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
     <img src="images/6.png" class="image_wall_thumbnail" />
</div>
```

then the jQuery:

```
var slide = 1;

function slideshow() {
    $("#container").find("img").animate({opacity:0});
    setTimeout('$("#container").find("img").hide();',400);
    setTimeout('$("#container").find("[src='images/"+slide+".png']").show();',400);
    setTimeout('$("#container").find("[src='images/"+slide+".png']").animate({opacity:1});',400);
    slide++;
}

var slideshow = setInterval("slideshow();",3000);
```

also, set the opacity to 0 and display to none for all the images. This code has not beenj tested so you might have to make some minor adjustments.

Comment: I see you have your own interpretation of "random" and "minor adjustments". Also, why not use the fadein/out functions that jQuery already provides?

Comment: First time I've heard of those.

Comment: No offence meant, @thomas, but it really looks like you put, little to no effort into this answer. The syntax is not even valid - never mind the logic behind it. These are the reasons for my vote.

Comment: as i said, this is just to give an idea of how its supposed to work. I never said to just copy and paste this into the project

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you're just trying to help - but if you don't even have enough time to post valid syntax then maybe you shouldn't post it. Or not post code and just pseudo code that will convey the logic you imagine... As it currently stands your answer is not really helping anyone. It's not clear what your logic is at all. Perhaps some explanations and/or comments will help fix this.